# How can I define a method on a class except for its certain subclass?

Tags: ruby

I want to define a method on a class except for its certain subclass on which the same method name is already defined.

For example, I want to define a method `name` on `Object` and let it be accessible from `Object` and its subclasses except for `Module` and its subclasses, on which `name` already exists. What is the best way to do this?

My attempt is this:

```
class Object
  class ::Module; alias orig_name name end
  def name
    ...
  end
  class ::Module; alias name orig_name end
end
```

Is there a better way of doing this perhaps using `prepend`?

Comment: I can't answer but still trying to understand .... seems like you don't want a "mixin" to override a method, but it is OK for a subclass to override a method?

Comment: Sorry, the question didn't make much sense.

Comment: Oh, well. Win a few, lose a few, but keep the questions coming--most are a treat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this how `def` already works?

```
class Object
  def name
    "This is my name"
  end
end

Module.name # => "Module"
Class.name  # => "Class"
String.name # => "String"
Object.new.name # => "This is my name"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just define your method at Object. As Module's ancestor is Object it will look first at Module then at Object.

```
class Object
  def name
    puts self.class
  end
end

class Module < Object
  def name
    puts "name #{self.class}"
  end
end

Object.new.name
# => Object
Module.new.name
# => name Module
```

If you create new classes inheriting from Object and Module:

```
class ObjectInheritance < Object
end

class ModuleInheritance < Module
end

ObjectInheritance.new.name
# => ObjectInheritance
ModuleInheritance.new.name
# => name ModuleInheritance
```

Ruby will look up for methods first in self, then included modules, then ancestors classes.